# How to start/test/try Bootstrap example?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm

I have downloaded the Bootstrap 4.1 source from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/. I want to just test, or run it. I thought it is enough to just open `index.html`, and view the executed source as an HTML document. It is definitely not running as expected.

Please, help a newbie.

Answer (score 5):

On that page in your post ( https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/ ) , you have a link to 'download the source code'. What you have downloaded is the source code for the Bootstrap 4.1 framework, which can also be found on their Github here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

I believe what you're looking for is a way to run the example templates that you saw, and that you are not interested in the entire source code behind the Bootstrap framework to build it or modify it yourself. You just want to *use* it. What you have downloaded, is possibly overkill for your needs.

To actually use Bootstrap, hop over to http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/, and I would suggest you use their CDNs as shown there (Content Delivery Networks - the quickest, easiest way -- those servers are hosting the JavaScript and CSS files for you. You don't need to even download them to your own disk) if you just want to run/demo the examples you were looking at.

To use and modify those Boostrap examples (i.e. to open `index.html` and view the example: HTML, JavaScript, CSS) , you will find them in that ZIP of the entire Bootstrap source code you downloaded, and that is why it links you to the entire source of Bootstrap. They are in this directory:

`bootstrap-4.1.3.zip\bootstrap-4.1.3\site\docs\4.1\examples`

Let's take a look at the `album` example included within their ZIP archive. If we go ahead and open up `index.html`, we can see our web browser will simply load the HTML. The CSS and JavaSript are not executed. To confirm this, we can usually hit F12 to open most web browser's (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE/Edge, etc) Web Developer Tools, and look at the `Console` section. We see with this example, `album`, we are getting a `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` for `bootstrap.min.css`, `popper.min.js`, `bootstrap.min.js`, `holder.min.js`, `favicon.ico`.

Let's take a look at the code behind album's `index.html`. Looking at line 13, we can see:
`<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
So that directory path match where out `bootstrap.min.css` file is? The same for the linked `favicon.ico` on line 8. Looking at the bottom of `index.html`, we can see this is where all of the JavaScript is linked. Firstly, we have a jQuery CDN on line 226. We have that loaded, so that is why we did not see that `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Further more, we have multiple JavaScript files like `popper.js` and `bootstrapmin.min.js` to name a few, that probably do not match our directory structure.

Extracting all of the archive for `bootstrap-4.1.3.zip`, and then trying to open `album`'s `index.html`, I still see that we actually get a `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` for `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js`. It is because they have made an error linking
you to JavaScript and CSS files that do not exist on disk/that directory structure.

To fix it:
On line 12-13, change it to this:

`<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../../../../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

And on line 229, change to this:

`<script src="../../../../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Save the file, refresh the page, and the example will work. You will also see we do not have any errors in the web developer console pane.

To confirm, you do *not* need the Apache server or the PHP language (WAMP, XAMPP). You are not serving PHP files, and purely client-side technologies: CSS, JavaScript, HTML. Bootstrap is a front-end framework.

Comment: it's really detailed.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a template for a website. You'll have to set up a webserver which will serve the content and scripts to your browser.

If you're running Windows, [WAMPP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) will set one up for you on your machine.

After the setup you'll be able to browse to http://localhost to see your site.
They both set up a dashboard page.

If you want to continue here to setup your bootstrap example you'll have to locate the "www" or "htdocs" folder and clean it out, throw in the bootstrap source and then use your browser to navigate to http://localhost again.

If you want to keep the dashboard page you'll have to create a new folder in "htdocs" or "www" and throw the source in there. Then navigate to http://localhost/newfoldername to view it in your browser.

Comment: So, it needs a server? But it is just a simple http page (examples). I though that It doesn't need a server. Am I wrong? I just wanted to download this example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/product/

Comment: The thing is, the page requests several files to be loaded(javascript, css, etc.) and methinks it can't find the correct files to load, and therefor it wouldn't function correctly.